# How to use for loop instead of foreach loop

Tags: c#

In my code there is a foreach() loop I want to replace it by for loop

```
foreach (string key in Request.Form.Keys)
```

I want to run this loop only one time

how i do this

Comment: Out of interest...why?

Comment: What do *you* mean by "run this loop only one time"? Why do you think a foreach fails and a for-loop will help?

Comment: If you want to run the loop only once, don't even bother with for or foreach, just take the first item like Request.Form.Keys[0] and execute your logic with that one item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < Request.Form.Keys.Count; i++)
{
    string key = Request.Form.Keys[i];
    string value = Request.Form[key];
}
```

Comment: for(i=0;i<Request.Form.Keys.Count;i++)

Comment: Thanks I  typed too fast. But anyway why downvotes?

Comment: I dont know... I dont make a downvote

Comment: @AstralisSomnium Because your code didn't work. Also, it still won't compile as `object` is reserved.

Comment: i want to run this loop one time only

Comment: It will loop only one time. and if you mean only get the first item, you can add `break;` after `string value = Request.Form[key];`"and it will jump out! But then you dont need a for/foreach.

Answer (score -1):

```
 String key=String.Empty;
 for(int i=0;i<Request.Form.Keys.Count;i++)
    {
     key =Request.Form.Keys[i];
    //run the loop.
    }
```

if you want to run only once you can use break as below:

**Solution2 :**

```
        String key=String.Empty;
        for(int i=0;i<Request.Form.Keys.Count;i++)
        {
         key =Request.Form.Keys[i];
        //run the loop only once


        break;
        }
```

Comment: Where is the `string key` variable?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Thanks for your valuable comment.please check now.

Comment: @Sudhaker i want to run this loop only one time

Comment: @bheeshamkumarsharma: then you can use `break;` check my edited answer with solution2